# Allow single instance for Q-Dir file manager

Tags: single-instance, qdir

I have [Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir) as the default file program and when I open a new folder, it opens another instance of Q-Dir.

But I want to restrict it only to a single instance.

Is there a way to allow only single instance for Q-Dir? I searched the web but could not find a solution.

N.B.

I am a Win-7 user and running a portable version of Q-Dir

Comment: Why not ask the developer to include such an option? It might be possible to have an AutoHotkey script or similar program constantly monitoring processes and killing any new instances of Q-Dir besides the original, but I think this would be an ugly solution even if implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option was right below my nose. The language is a little different so could not catch it.

[image]